# Ошибки в Справке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

В Справке, в разделе "Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»?", нужно исправить "в течении" на "в течение" (в двух местах) и убрать запятую:

*Вопрос автоматически попадает в очередь на повторное открытие, если в течени**И** пяти дней с момента получения статуса «требующий правки»**(,)** он был изменён.*

*Автор вопроса, отмеченного как [требующего правки], имеет возможность внести улучшающую правку в течени**И** пяти дней.*

Пропущена Ю:

*...это прекрасно, но они тоже с большой вероятность**Ю** не подходят для формата вопросов и ответов.*

И ещё исправить "вопроса" на "вопрос":

*...в обоих состояниях на вопрос**А** нельзя дать ответ...*

Comment: Спасибо! Всё исправлено.